# embedded tomcat server not running

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I am using a Raspberry PI and the Pi4J to control some relays. I want to be able to control these relays from an android app. To do so I am using an example code in [here](https://github.com/heroku/devcenter-embedded-tomcat) . What this does is to start an embedded tomcat server and an example servlet. I think that this is what I need to call RestFUL methods from my phone to my raspberry. I've tried this code and works perfectly on my windows 10. 
To deploy the app on my Raspberry I modified pom.xml to package a Jar and to send it to my raspberry PI.

When I run it on netbeans, I amb able to compile it and deploy it on my Raspberry PI. However, when I open a browser, I get 404 error when I navigate to http://localhost:8080 . It is a tomcat server error page which tells me tomcat server is running somehow, but I don't see the "hellow haroku" message as it is supposed to.

What do you think is wrong? Why is it working on my windows pc and not on my raspberry?

this is the modified pom.xml file to pack a jar and send it to my raspberry PI

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.heroku.sample</groupId>
  <artifactId>embeddedTomcatSample</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>embeddedTomcatSample Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <tomcat.version>8.0.28</tomcat.version>
    <!-- DEFAULT RASPBERRY PI PROPERTIES -->
    <pi.host>192.168.1.122</pi.host>
    <pi.port>22</pi.port>
    <pi.user>pi</pi.user>
    <pi.password>mypassword</pi.password>
    <pi.deployDirectory>/home/pi/doorSYS</pi.deployDirectory>
    <pi.main.class>launch.Main</pi.main.class>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.pi4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>pi4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jasper-el</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>embeddedTomcatSample</finalName>

    <plugins>

        <!-- This plugin will generate JAR MANIFEST file inside the JAR in order to make our applicationeasily runnable -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>${pi.main.class}</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-my-jar-with-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

     <!--This plugin will Transfer the executable JAR file to the Pi and runs it -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <!-- ensure the target directory exists on the Raspberry Pi -->
                            <sshexec host="${pi.host}" port="${pi.port}" username="${pi.user}" password="${pi.password}" 
                                     trust="true" failonerror="false" verbose="true" 
                                     command="mkdir --parents ${pi.deployDirectory}"/>

                            <!-- copy the JAR file to the Raspberry Pi -->
                            <scp
                                file="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-jar-with-dependencies.jar"
                                todir="${pi.user}:${pi.password}@${pi.host}:${pi.deployDirectory}"
                                port="${pi.port}" trust="true" verbose="true" failonerror="true">
                            </scp> 

                            <!-- run the JAR file on the Raspberry Pi -->
                            <sshexec host="${pi.host}" port="${pi.port}" username="${pi.user}"
                                     password="${pi.password}" trust="true" failonerror="false"
                                     verbose="true" 
                                     command="java -jar ${pi.deployDirectory}/${project.build.finalName}-jar-with-dependencies.jar"/>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ant-jsch</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9.6</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <assembleDirectory>target</assembleDirectory>
                <programs>
                    <program>
                        <mainClass>launch.Main</mainClass>
                        <name>webapp</name>
                    </program>
                </programs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assemble</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

These is the output of java -jar embeddedtomcat.jar

> application resolved root folder: /home/pi/doorSYS disabling TLD
>   scanning configuring app with basedir:
>   /tmp/default-doc-base5315596104031704189 Apr 24, 2016 6:04:10 PM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"] Apr 24, 2016 6:04:10 PM
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector INFO:
>   Using a shared selector for servlet write/read Apr 24, 2016 6:04:10 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal INFO: Starting
>   service Tomcat Apr 24, 2016 6:04:10 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal INFO: Starting
>   Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.28 Apr 24, 2016 6:04:11 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig getDefaultWebXmlFragment
>   INFO: No global web.xml found Apr 24, 2016 6:04:13 PM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]

thats the error page I get

[image]

Comment: Share your web.xml setting. What is the welcome page attribute set to?

Comment: I have no web.xml file, yet it is working on windows.